# XML extraction with R

Tags: xml, r

I am using R to extract data from XML which looks like this ('atbat' is a higher node than 'pitch'):

```
<atbat num="1" b="2" s="2" o="1" start_tfs="173619" start_tfs_zulu="2014-06-
01T17:36:19Z" batter="543706" stand="R" b_height="5-8" pitcher="543699"  
p_throws="R" des="Daniel Robertson grounds out to first baseman Adam  
LaRoche.
  <pitch des="Ball" des_es="Bola mala" id="3" type="B" tfs="173525" 
  tfs_zulu="2014-06-01T17:35:25Z" x="129.61" y="114.84" event_num="3" 
  sv_id="140601_133543" play_guid="" start_speed="90.8" end_speed="84.1"
```

I am using the following R function and call to extract all of the data related to the pitches (this is baseball data):

```
grabXML <- function(XML.parsed, field){
  parse.field <- getNodeSet(XML.parsed, paste("//", field, sep=""))
  results <- t(sapply(parse.field, function(x) xmlAttrs(x)))  
  if(typeof(results)=="list"){
    do.call(rbind.fill, lapply(lapply(results, t), data.frame,  
    stringsAsFactors=F))
 } 
 else {
    as.data.frame(results, stringsAsFactors=F)
 }
}

xmlGame <- xmlParse(URL)
grabXML(xmlGame, "pitch")
```

The function does exactly what I want except that it returns ALL of the pitch data for the game. I would like to be able to specify a pitcher ID (notice that pitchers are identified by a 6-digit number in the XML) and have the function only return that pitch data. I am wondering if I possibly need a 'for' loop or if the fact that the pitcher ID is in a higher node would cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the `XML`-package?
You would use it like this:

```
library(XML)
xml.content <- xmlParse("file.xml")
# maneuver to the right node here
xml.content <- xmlRoot(xml.content)

# get the attributes
attrs <- xmlAttrs(xml.content)
attrs["pitch"]
```